# To fix "Load unsafe scripts"

Tags: javascript, php

I have used an external link (http://www.ex.com/). If i have used "https" in the external link, it will not work.  How to avoid the alert in which "load unsafe scripts" without using "https" in external link?

Comment: loading https resources in an http page works, it's the other way around that doesn't

Comment: You can't. The warning would be pretty useless if any site could simply disable it :-)

Comment: Well you can, you have to fix it :P if you open console, it will tell you which resources that you need to get to link to https instead of http.

Comment: @Farkie - question says https in the external link doesn't work!

Comment: many external libraries etc, especially ones in CDN's, support both http and https ... the usual way to refer to them is simply `//host.com/resource` - by ommitting the protocol from the URL, the browser will use whatever the protocol of the current document is (http or https) - not sure that will help you, but it's good to know

Comment: It will work, but he'll get loading unsafe scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable these errors because they're security warnings, however I would suggest you could look at [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for free SSL Certs for your external resource.

Comment: LetsEncrypt wont help with `external resource` - by definition, an external resource would be one that is **not** under ones control :p

Comment: @JaromandaX not entirely true, I often have resources hosted externally, S3 / CDN's and sometimes, depending on the use-case those are also hosted on a server I *do* have control of, and therefore I'm sure my comment might help somebody.

Comment: fair enough - still the question actually says that the problem is when the external resource is https!

Comment: He says when he tries to use HTTPS it doesn't work. For me that reads that the external resource doesn't provide a HTTPS version. But I may be mistaken

Comment: No, you're probably right - there's many ways the question can be interpreted :p

Comment: True. It's a little open-ended haha